# How to define a function that calculates the BMI from dataframe(Python)

Tags: python

I need to define a function that will calculate and return out of **dataframe** that includes columns "Height" and "Weight", the BMI of each row.
Here is the code that i wrote:

```
import pandas as pd
def BMI(DataFrame):
    df=pd.DataFrame
    return df['Weight']/df['Height']^2
```

But when I try to run that function with:

```
data.apply(BMI,axis=1)
```

when "data" is my dataframe,

the result is an error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6487, in apply
    return op.get_result()
  File "D:\Python Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 151, in get_result
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "D:\Python Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 257, in apply_standard
    self.apply_series_generator()
  File "D:\Python Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 286, in apply_series_generator
    results[i] = self.f(v)
  File "<input>", line 3, in BMI
TypeError: ("'type' object is not subscriptable", 'occurred at index 0')`

What went wrong with my code?

Comment: *the result is an error.* what is an error? and why you are passing dataframe to function?

Comment: edit the question and post it!!

Comment: @David additional info should be edited into the question (there is a `edit` link under the text of the question). There is not sufficient formatting in the comments so we cannot read that info easily.

Comment: Sorry, i edited my post and added the error i get.

Answer (score 3):

Just came across this by accident, please note that the correct formula for BMI is:

> [image: \BMI = \frac{WEIGHT_{kg}}{HEIGHT_{m}^{2}}]

Therefore,

```
p = pd.DataFrame({'H': [1.83, 1.80], 'W': [70, 80]})
p.apply(lambda x: (x.W/(x.H**2)), axis=1)
```

which yields

```
0    20.902386
1    24.691358
dtype: float64
```

please note the additional brackets in the denominator of the formula that apply the squared term only to the height in meters (they are not absolutely necessary, but I added them to emphasise which term is squared).

correct formulas can be found under
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index

Answer (score 1):

You have a few syntax errors,

first `^2` does not work in python, is `**2`, and Why are you defining a `DataFrame` inside your function?

This should work:

```
p = pd.DataFrame({'H': [183, 180], 'W': [70, 80]})
p.apply(lambda x: (x.W/x.H)**2, axis=1)

Out[17]: 
0    0.146317
1    0.197531
dtype: float64
```